# Eureka registration of Https micro services

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

Eureka does not recognized HTTPS endpoints like '/info' and '/health' and always points to HTTP endpoints after enabling HTTPS. How to enable HTTPS micro-service url registration at Eureka ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to explicitly define these URLs as Eureka always points to HTTP internally. Read [Here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_registering_a_secure_application) for more about it.

You can add following into your yaml file in the microservice.

```
eureka:
   instance: 
      nonSecurePortEnabled: false
      securePortEnabled: true
      statusPageUrl: 'https://${eureka.instance.hostName}:${server.port}/info'
      healthCheckUrl: 'https://${eureka.instance.hostName}:${server.port}/health'
      homePageUrl: 'https://${eureka.instance.hostName}:${server.port}/'
```

Here *"eureka.instance.hostName"* and *"server.port"* values will be taken from the environment.

Answer (score 2):

For me this configuration works:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    nonSecurePortEnabled: false
    securePortEnabled: true
    securePort: ${server.port}
    statusPageUrl: https://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${eureka.instance.securePort}/info
    homePageUrl: https://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${eureka.instance.securePort}/
```

Answer (score 0):

For me below configuration works fine:-

```
eureka:
   instance:
     statusPageUrl: https://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}/actuator/info
     healthCheckUrl: https://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}/health
     homePageUrl: https://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}/
```